# Did I install correctly the wireless card driver?

Tags: linux, firmware, wifi-driver

I am trying to fix the WiFi connection on an Asus E200 laptop, following these instructions: https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/E200HA.
The laptop has the latest LXLE distribution, with a kernel updated to version 4.15. The wireless card is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377.

I have downloaded the non free driver (https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-atheros) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ./firmware-atheros-20190114-1_all.deb
```

I had to uninstall the `linux-firmware` package to install the non free driver. Then I ran:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

and rebooted. I am not sure this is the right procedure and, since I am getting the same errors as with the free driver, I am wondering if I made a mistake or missed a step somewhere.

Comment: LXLE is based on Ubuntu. so, you should be following instructions for Ubuntu. Installing Debian specific packages, especially those related to firmware/drivers is usually NOT a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending way too much time following various threads and possible solutions, I am giving up. If somebody has a Linux laptop with this wireless card, my suggestion is to get a  USB cable and set up tethering with an Android smartphone. Takes 5 min and works quite well.